# If div contains a span with a class based on parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create a simple function that create span's with an class that equals whatever is piped into the function. These spans fill inside a parent div. I also want to ensure that once a span has been added that another span is not add with that id/class, unless my `multiSearchEnabled` boolean is true.

Here is some code i've

```
function createBadge(badge_type) {
    var badge_parent_div = $("#badge-column-div");
    var badge = "<span class='badge-text " + badge_type + "'>" + badge_type + "</span>";

    if (!$(badge_parent_div.find("span").hasClass(badge_type))) {
        badge_parent_div.append(badge);
    } else {
        if (multiSearchEnabled) {
            badge_parent_div.append(badge); // Add another Badge, since search contains multiples
         }
    }
  }
```

However this doesnt seem to work, this function will be ran `onKeyUp` therefore is why i need to detect if the span already exists for this type, so i dont duplicate it.

### Updated based on suggestions

```
function createBadge(badge_type) {
 var badge = "<span class='" + badge_type + "'>" + badge_type + "</span>";
 var bHasBadge = $("#badge-column-div").has('.' + badge_type);

 if (bHasBadge == false || (bHasBadge && multiSearchEnabled == true))
 {
     // add it
     $("#badge-column-div").append(badge);
 }
}
```

However with the following code, nothing ever get's added. I need it add a badge initially, then only if the multiSearchEnabled boolean is true to add more than one.

Comment: You can old have one element per id... Perhaps you could use 'class' instead of 'id'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) checks for child controls matching a selector.

```
function createBadge(sBadgeType) 
{
    var oBadgeParent = $("#badge-column-div");
    var bHasBadge    = oBadgeParent.has("span." + sBadgeType)

    if (bHasBadge == false || bMultiSearchEnabled) 
        oBadgeParent.append
        (
            $("<span class='badge-text " +sBadgeType+ "'>" +sBadgeType+ "</span>")
        );
}
```

Comment: Brett, This is very close to what i need. I have tried the code, what is happening is the span is being added multiple times. since this code gets ran onkeyup in a input. I have a function that detects search types and then based on type creates this span badge, i need to ensure the badge only gets added once in the parent div unless the boolean is true.

Comment: @JaisonBrooks I think this may be what you are looking for. Sorry. I rushed through it first time through, didn't capture the requirements completely

Comment: I've updated my question with the full code im working with, your code is great but its still not add at least one badge initially. Any ideas?

Comment: Im struggling to find out why your code is not working, it makes complete sense and was written really nice. But for some reason if statement is not returning true.

Comment: Hey Brett, I've created a jsfiddle here => http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonbrooks/fjemdw02/  This includes an example of what im working with. you maybe able to find my issue.

Comment: I took a look.. I cannot find any errors, but I am not getting the console.log message, either. I'm not sure what direction to go on this. :/

Comment: Haven't yet found the actual solution, however this has gotten me way closer than before. Answer accepted, thank you Brett.